# Why people like aligning function parameters with the left parenthesis?

Tags: c++, c, indentation, google-style-guide

I saw many repositories using google c++ style, they format function parameters like this

```
void Foo(int param1, int param2,
         int param3, int param4,
         int param5, int param6)
```

or

```
void Foo(int param1, int param2, int param3, int param4,
         int param5)
```

or

```
void Foo(int param1,
         int param2,
         int param3,
         int param4)
```

I know this style makes the parameters stand out, but if we had to rename `Foo` to `FooBar`, the first parameter wouldn't be in the same column with other parameters. Like this,

```
void FooBar(int param1,
        int param2,
        int param3,
        int param4)
```

Do they have to format the whole project again to make all parameters of `FooBar` in the same column?

Comment: There are two questions here. Which are you asking?

Comment: Good editors have good refactoring (including renaming) functionality as well as good handling of the selected code-style and its indentation, so it's usually not a problem or very simple and easy to handle.

Comment: Tooks like `clang-format` (often also integrated into editors and IDEs) make this a non-issue. For example; every time I save a file in QtCreator it is automatically reformatted to follow the style I've configured, so I never think about formatting while writing the code - I just save and magically everything I just wrote as a mess suddenly looks nice.

Comment: Side note with this many arguments... it starts to make sense to pass a struct. The rest is just that... style. Which is just likely to end in opinions, only one thing matters whatever style you choose apply it consistently

Comment: just to [illustrate the point](https://youtu.be/zd_aDbwr4pY?t=153) .. at work we have a git hook setup that runs a linter (clang-format/tidy?) every time you commit... the only kicker is occasionally the local linter and pipeline linter disagree, so then you have to change your code to code around the formatting so the pipeline will pass .. that really irritates me heh

Comment: All these alternatives look ugly to me.

Comment: I think this style is unfriendly for function rename.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All code styles like that will need to be reformatted anytime you change something. c'est la vie.

The common excuse for formatting like the 3rd example is that any variable change will affect only 1 line, and not affect source control diffs so much. Obviously if you change the function name itself then the diff will change all parameters. This can be a good thing - it shows the function changed and not the 1st parameter.

In short, there are much better things to worry about than indentation styles being good or bad. Just ensure you follow whatever is already there as changing from 1 style to another is the worst thing anyone can do.